# Meteor: How to make Bootstrap Select reactive?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, meteor, bootstrap-select

When using Bootstrap multiselect, I find that the multiselect jquery always fires a little bit too early - before the template has finished pulling data from the helpers, and as a result the select boxes are often empty (I'd say about 60% of the time).

Clearly Template.usersLayout.rendered() is not the right place to call functions that rely on data to have been rendered. What is a better way to do this?

Alternatively, I guess making the bootstrap-select javascript 'reactive would be 1st prize. How can I do this?

code is below

==========

I'm using a helper (#each) to create a select box where each option is it's own data context.

```
<template name="usersLayout">
    <form>
        <!-- Multiselect for instruments -->
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="playerInstruments">Player instruments</label>
            <div class="controls text-left">
                <select id="playerInstruments" multiple="multiple" class="selectFilter" name="playerInstruments">
                    {{#each instruments}}
                    <option value="{{name}}">{{name}}</option>
                    {{/each}}
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</template>
```

The helper is defined as follows:

```
Template.usersLayout.helpers({

    /* Database retrievals */

    // Returns all Instruments from Mongo
    instruments: function() {
        return Instruments.find();
    }

})
```

The twitter bootstrap code is all something like the following:

```
Template.usersLayout.rendered = function () {

    $('#playerInstruments').multiselect({
        disableIfEmpty: true,
        onChange: function(option, checked) {
            // Set the session as the checked valuess
            var tempSessionArr = $("#playerInstruments").val();
            // Add or delete from Session
            Session.set('playerInstruments', tempSessionArr);
        },
    });
}
```

Comment: How did you subscribe to the data? on the router ? Can you show us the subscribe code ?

Comment: no, I haven't subscribed yet. I haven't added the security settings yet that require subscription (I think). But this is my first meteor app, please correct me if that makes no sense.

Comment: I'm using flow-router, which incidentally is causing problems when loading new pages with other bootstrap-select requirements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your template does not wait for the data before it start to render, Since data only appears on page after template already rendered, select box is empty. I know that this is your first app and you did not remove the `autopublish` package, but it is a best practice to follow the full tutorial from Flow Router

First of all, read [this](https://github.com/kadirahq/flow-router#subscription-management). Then, change your router to have the `subcriptions` options. After that, check if the subscriptions are ready through [this](https://github.com/kadirahq/flow-router#flowroutersubsready-with-a-callback) (the `subsReady()` should be inside the `rendered` function) and then, in the `callback` of the `subsReady()`, init the selectbox

Comment: I assume you mean Tracker.subsReady(), and not Tracker.subReady()?

Comment: I mean subsReady of Flow Router

Answer (score 0):

You want to use [template events](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/template_events) to catch the change event instead of setting up a jQuery hook.

```
Template.usersLayout.events({
  '#playerInstruments change': function(ev){
    var tempSessionArr = $("#playerInstruments").val();
    Session.set('playerInstruments', tempSessionArr);
  },
});
```

Then keep your `multiselect` setup in the `onRendered` handler:

```
Template.usersLayout.rendered = function () {
  $('#playerInstruments').multiselect({ disableIfEmpty: true });
};
```

If this still doesn't work try wrapping the latter with `defer`:

```
Template.usersLayout.rendered = function () {
  Meteor.defer(function(){
    $('#playerInstruments').multiselect({ disableIfEmpty: true });
  });
};
```

Comment: No I don't think that would work as I then cannot call the multiselect() function?

Comment: This is very hacky... Meteor.defer seems to be equivalent to setTimeout(), which means effectively I would be 'hoping' that the select boxes were populated by the time I run multiselect(). There is no guarantee of this - it 'will probably' work except when it doesn't.

Comment: @Thai is right that if your subscription has not loaded when you render this template then the `{{#each}}` won't run until the data becomes available. So from a reactive pov, the template is rendered but you have nothing in your multiselect. You don't mention your subscriptions anywhere but that's a good place to look. `Meteor.defer()` is helpful when you want to allow pending UI changes to be drawn before your js runs.